# Need help with logo concept

Tags: logo, identity, conceptualization

I'm given this slogan to work with: "Fast Forward, Rewind, Pause, & Unwind".  And I need to visually represent what this slogan conveys.

This logo is for a library association.
Since I'm working on a very short notice, I don't have a lot of time thinking about this logo, which is why I'm in need of help from a graphic design community.

Please let me know how I can visually convey "Fast Forward, Rewind, Pause, & Unwind"

Thanks ahead of time

Comment: The repetition of "wind" makes it a bit of a clumsy slogan, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Don't get too hung up on being literal with the slogan.  Take a look at this [list of company slogans](http://www.crews.org/curriculum/ex/compsci/8thgrade/company_slogans.htm). Very few, if any, have any connection with the logo. Plus slogans can change and, hopefully, the logo is a more permanent feature.

I would make this case to the client. Instead the logo should encapsulate the association itself. Libraries, books, media, learning, perhaps a connection to the community the Association serves.

When faced with requests like this, I usually give the client what they asked for, and then I show them what they need.  Most of the time they end up going with the second choice, it's just they lack the imagination to come up most of the ideas on their own, which is why they hired us in the first place right?

Comment: Completely agree. Aside from a few big brands who've spent the GDP of an average 1st world nation to burn their tagline into the public's frontal lobe, taglines are like a campaign. It will be used for a season to drive home some strategic message. After that period it should evolve or be done away with completely.

Answer (score 2):

"Fast forward" "rewind" and "pause" have symbols associated with them which are very deeply embedded in our culture. The next step is how to apply them to something which one might use for unwinding. I can think of several things one might associate with unwinding in an adult context. Once you figure out what that might be, you nearly done.

Comment: Then there is one element more: the library association. What is its target audience? What exactly is the library that it is an association for?

Comment: Right: Library Association Singles Mixer has different requirments as opposed to a Symposium: Beta Max vs VHS

Answer (score 2):

"And I need to visually represent what this slogan conveys."

Why? The slogan already conveys that. Given your short time, I'd spruce up the slogan with some nice type design and make that the logo.

Comment: Well, the previous slogans for the library associations were visually represented.  But the slogans used objective terms and were easy to represent.  This one is all conceptual and harder to visually represent.

Answer (score 1):

What is associated with a library? exactly, books.
So maybe it is an idea to put the symbols on the book or actually pressed into the book.
Fairly easy to make.

For the unwind icon i would look for something like this:

[image]

Hope this will get you started. With a little imagination you can mock up a logo design for this easily. All the elements are there.

Comment: Perhaps make the unwind icon look more like a hammock to go with the idea of unwinding / relaxing?